# ResourcesNotFoundException in account sync setting

Tags: android, preferences, accountmanager

I implement custom account using account manager in my project. Everything is fine but when I click in my account in Accounts and sync page in settings system crashes and restarts. I tracked it down by DDMS. Here is my Logcat:

```
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/(2895): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_sys_error
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.providers.subscribedfeeds/com.android.settings.AccountSyncSettings}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:632)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.settings.AccountPreferenceBase.getLabelForType(AccountPreferenceBase.java:160)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.settings.AccountSyncSettings.onAuthDescriptionsUpdated(AccountSyncSettings.java:450)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.settings.AccountPreferenceBase.updateAuthDescriptions(AccountPreferenceBase.java:200)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at com.android.settings.AccountSyncSettings.onCreate(AccountSyncSettings.java:177)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-15 20:51:39.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2895):     ... 6 more
```

and this is my prefs.xml for account page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Dortan Preferences" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

what causes this exception?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Which part? I think the only part that affects accounts and sync part is the xml that I posted. am I right?

Comment: The problem can be in JAVA code.

Comment: Nothing in java code is related to this part. It's just a authenticator.xml with a this line 'android:accountPreferences="@xml/prefs"'